# How to apply custom theme in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply a custom theme to my React component after reading this tutorial

http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

I wrote my theme in a separate javascript file like this

```
import Colors from 'material-ui/lib/styles/colors';
import ColorManipulator from 'material-ui/lib/utils/color-manipulator';
import Spacing from 'material-ui/lib/styles/spacing';
import zIndex from 'material-ui/lib/styles/zIndex';

export default {
  spacing: Spacing,
  zIndex: zIndex,
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  palette: {
    primary1Color: Colors.cyan500,
    primary2Color: Colors.cyan700,
    primary3Color: Colors.lightBlack,
    accent1Color: Colors.pinkA200,
    accent2Color: Colors.grey100,
    accent3Color: Colors.grey500,
    textColor: Colors.deepPurpleA700,
    alternateTextColor: Colors.white,
    canvasColor: Colors.white,
    borderColor: Colors.grey300,
    disabledColor: ColorManipulator.fade(Colors.darkBlack, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: Colors.cyan500,
  }
};
```

I apply this theme to my component in the follow way

```
import React from 'react';
import mui from 'material-ui';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import ThemeManager from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager';
import Colors from 'material-ui/lib/styles/colors';
import MyTheme from './theme.js';

injectTapEventPlugin();

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            messages : [{id: 1, text: 'Hi'}, {id: 2, text: 'Hello'}]
        };
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(MyTheme)
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        let newMuiTheme = this.state.muiTheme;
        this.setState({
            muiTheme: newMuiTheme,
        });     
    }

    render() {

        var messageNodes = this.state.messages.map((message) => {
            return (<div key={message.id}>{message.text}</div>);
        });
        return (<div>{messageNodes}</div>);
    }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default App;
```

According to my theme when my control renders it should have a "deepPurpleA700" color .... but my control text is always black. So my theme is not applied.

My full code is available at https://github.com/abhitechdojo/MovieLensReact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to have

```
static childContextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

before your

```
getChildContext()
```

method. Once that is done you should be able to remove any theme related stuff from 
    componentWillMount()

Now, this won't work for base text. But I can confirm that the theme is being applied. I tested it by adding an appBar component and changing the color in your theme.js file. I also added a List with ListItems and that text style is what you are looking for.

Here is a link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikedklein/37a5b847fb3983dc5efc) of your modified App.jsx file.

Also, as a side note in you server.js you have a small typo on line 5 you should have

```
new webpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
```

not

```
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
```

Answer (score 13):

You should first import your color from 'material-ui/styles/colors'
and then use them in palette object like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {indigo500, indigo700, redA200} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

import Main from './Main';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary1Color: indigo500,
        primary2Color: indigo700,
        accent1Color: redA200,
        pickerHeaderColor: indigo500,
    },
});

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                    <Main />
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app')); //you should be having a div with an id of app in your index.html file
```

and the Main.js file is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';


export default class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar title="Title"/>
                <FloatingActionButton secondary={true} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For me it worked with:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#0b5994',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#1d83c6',
        },
    },
});

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    /* content here! */
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```